# Heroku deployment : Something is already running on port ****

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, web-deployment

I tried to deploy my app (ReactJs-NodeJs-Mongo) on Heroku.

But i got a problem when i tried to start it, i got a error message with "Something is already running on port ****".

My back is running, but not my front.

It's the first time i try to deploy on Heroku. So i'm missing something about it.

How can i fix this issue ?

Link to my git : https://github.com/romainbor/eteach

here is my index.js in my server folder :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const security = require('./middleware/security');
const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
const AnnonceRouter = require('./routes/annonce');
const securityRouter = require('./routes/security');
const commentRouter = require('./routes/comment');
const mailRouter = require('./routes/mail')
const path = require('path');


const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const PORT_CHAT = 3231


const app = express();

//app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build')));

const cors = require('cors');


var chat = require('http').createServer()
var io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(chat)

const SocketManager = require('./SocketManager')

io.on('connection', SocketManager)

chat.listen(PORT_CHAT, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT_CHAT);
})

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(security.verifyToken);
app.use('/', securityRouter);
app.use('/annonce', AnnonceRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/comment', commentRouter);
app.use('/mail', mailRouter);


// Serve static assets if in production
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')) // relative path
})

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.error(`Node ${isDev ? 'dev server' : 'cluster worker '+process.pid}: listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

my package.json at the root :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"cd server && node index.js\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

I got all my console.log running from my back : "app is listening on port ****" etc.
but for my front

2019-08-17T13:16:53.800476+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 32879.
2019-08-17T13:16:53.840457+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd client && npm start exited with code 0

If you have any idea of what am i doing wrong, i'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
chat.listen(PORT_CHAT, function () {
  console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT_CHAT);
});
```

to

```
chat.listen(process.env.PORT_CHAT || PORT_CHAT, function () {
  console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT_CHAT);
});
```

And try to set PORT_CHAT enviroment variable to value you need